# how to get rid of the expansion?

Tags: java, servlets

Hi I help do I then took to ***myName*** parameter was no extension, I have tried to do this with regular expressions:

```
String myName = request.getParameter("text").replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", "");
```

But we did not help to make it)

***myName*** parameter takes the file names, I need to be without the help to do it
Come listen to explain clearer: here I enter into the form (standard html form)
the name of the file, it any, whether or indeks.html indeks.tht, myname parameter accepts that I have introduced, but he accepts it as indeks.html, and I need to accept it without permission, ie, an example I introduced indeks.html in shape, the servlet that I took introduced, and then it will print it, but I need that he derived no indeks.html, just index, I hope now it is clear, ie to be able to input form and indeks.html and index, and a servlet anyway find a file)

Comment: Please try to be more clear. For now, your question is really not making much sense.

Comment: No idea what you're actually asking!

Comment: Can you give an example of what request.getParameter("text") is, what you want myName to be, and what result you are getting instead?

Comment: I get such a result (this is just an example to the fact I can get a different name and with a different extension) index.html would like to receive simple index without extension

Comment: It should already do that: http://ideone.com/fKO3PI are you sure the parameter is being read correctly?

Comment: Thank you both again, what I need, and if the file is not one, but such is mnogofaylov from a separate folder, and all of them need to remove the extension, please tell me an example

Comment: By the way, what you wrote does not work

Comment: String myNamee = request.getParameter("text");
        String myName = myNamee.replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", "");

Comment: Well, the problem is not solved yet someone has more ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i understood your trouble. You're looking to strip (cut off) extension from a value that is passed through text parameter (example: .html, .gif, .jpeg

This should help you. ( it cuts the value from first character Up to the first "."

```
  String myName = request.getParameter("text").substring(0, str.indexOf(".");
```

Please beware that that some characters are special and can appear encoded.

See this helpful chart:
http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm